How to read images from PIXTIFF compressed binaryfile
I have large size binary file comprised of several JFIF images. By looking at byte pattern and metadata i could figure out its PIXTIFF compressed.
Pixel Translation Inc., PIXTIFF Version 58.6


How can i read/extract images from this compressed binary file ?

Share the file on Google Drive or Dropbox for proper assistance. Or read here https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22093746/Reading-Pixel-Translations-Image-files.html

Also, tifffile documentation mentions PIXTIFF, but not sure if that is just a compression sub-type or the full PIXTIFF format.
